MYSQL Load Command Fails to Save Database
Running MYSQL on OPENSUSE 11. I wrote a bash script to load data from a csv file to a table in a new database. It appears to work - no error messages and the data is loaded into the table. However after the script is run and I run MYSQL and look at the new database, it's empty. It seems MYSQL rolled back the database.
I've tried local_infile=1 and GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to no avail.
Here's the script:
#!/bin/bash

# Default directory to read .csv files from
DIRECTORY="/var/lib/mysql-files/"
CSV_FILENAME=$DIRECTORY"sql_csv_test.csv"
SCHEMA_FILENAME=$DIRECTORY"sql_csv_test.sql"
NEW_DB_NAME="csv_test"

# Create database from .csv files
mysql -u root << QUERY
create database $NEW_DB_NAME;
use $NEW_DB_NAME;
source $SCHEMA_FILENAME;
set foreign_key_checks=0;
load data local infile '$CSV_FILENAME' into table BagEvent fields terminated by ',';
select * from BagEvent;
QUERY


What's in sql_csv_test.sql?

However after the script is run and I run MYSQL and look at the new database, it's empty. Empty - i.e. DB is created, tables are created too, but there is no data in the tables? Pause the script and look does the tables data files are filled with the data in the database directory - check file size, look in binary mode, query from another script or CLI.

@Barmar. The sql_csv_test.sql is a schema file created by mysqldump -u root --no-data --databases csv_test> sql_csv_test.sql

Unless the LOAD DATA statement is getting an error, I can't think of a reason why this doesn't do what you want. Does it work if you execute the commands by hand?

@Akina: The database is created but there are no tables. The select * from BagEvent displays the correct data in the table while the script is running.

When executing the commands by hand, the tables are created and the data is loaded into the BagEvent table. but when I exit mysql and rerun mysql, the database is there, but has no tables or data in it.

I entered the commands by hand and so created a database named q9 with the correct tables and data. Then I switched to a different database (use otherdbname;) then switched back to q9 (use q9;). The tables and data are not in database q9.

I found the error and I'll post it here in case someone else can benefit from this.

When saving the sql schema file use this command: mysqldump -u username --no-create-db --no-data databaseName > $schema.sql.  The error I was seeing was caused by the fact that I was using the --databases flag which inserted an sql use command in the schema file.
